# App Engine Google Console Dashboard

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

How can I view number of http requests for a given URI for my site deployed to App Engine? I see a dashboard in console.cloud.google.com. However I could not find any option that lists a count of each Http request for my website over a period of time?
Is there an option for App engine applications?

**Update:**
**App Engine->Dashboard->Current load** lists request counts for last 24 hours only.
**App engine->Dashboard->Select Request By type from Dropdown.** shows below graps with 0.002, 0.004, 0.006 etc metrics on the vertical axis. How would one translate this to x number of requests between << start date>> to << end date>>?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Console > App Engine > Dashboard.

Scroll down to "Current load" table. You can change selected period of time by clicking on various tabs at the top of this page.

Comment: This does not show count of request. It show each request hit time and latency. What I need is a summary of counts of requests. Such as "/foo/bar" - 34 hits between xxxx start date xxxxx end date.

Comment: It *does* show the count of request in the column "Requests (Last 24 hours)".

Comment: Thank. But its lists only for last 24 hours. What I need is a similar stats for a date range. Main App Engine->Dashboard shows a graph. I could select "Requests by type" from the dropdown. But the graph is difficult to understand. Its scale is not clear. It shows 0.002, 0.004 etc on the vertical axis.

Comment: What's not clear about "0.002 requests per second"?  I answered your question, but I am not responsible for building this product :)

Comment: See my update regarding "0.002 requests per second" query.

Comment: Since your original question was answered, consider accepting the answer and asking a new question that links back to this one for context instead of editing the question. See ['What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?'](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)

Comment: @adam original question was about http request count for a range of dates